# Excel VBA: VBProject.VBComponents("EstaPastadetrabalho").CodeModule.AddFromFile

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou tendo o erro no VBA do office 2013 referente a sintaxe abaixo, ao qual não ocorre no **Office 365**.

```
arq.VBProject.VBComponents("EstaPastadetrabalho").CodeModule.AddFromFile (FileWB)
```

Mensagem de erro gerado pelo **Office 2013**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMyr6.png

Código:

```
Set arq = Application.Workbooks.Add

arq.Sheets("OpçõesGerenciais").Select

' Importa o WorkBook ModuleWorkBook.cls para EstaPastadetrabalho (Excel em Português)

FileWB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FileGATI\ModuleWorkBook.cls"

arq.VBProject.VBComponents("EstaPastadetrabalho").CodeModule.AddFromFile (FileWB)
```

Comment: 1. Quando você cria uma pasta de trabalho nova (linha 1), nela já vem por padrão uma planilha chamada `OpçõesGerenciais`? 2. Você já deu um `debug.print FileWb` na linha imediatamente anterior ao erro, pra ver se a string efetivamente contém o caminho completo do seu arquivo .cls?

Comment: @CésarRodriguez ! a linha 1 (Set arq = Application.Workbooks.Add) quando executado, apenas cria uma nova planilha que em português chamado "Pasta1", assim a variável "arq = 'Pasta1' ...  Sobre o "debug.print" não cheguei a fazer, irei fazer e retorno aqui o resultado ... obrigado.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez fiz o teste do debug.print do conteúdo do FileWB (contém o valor esperado) e o erro permanece.

Comment: Se você clicar em Depurar na janela do erro, qual é a linha em que dá erro?